# How to acces store from imported submodule in nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js, store, git-submodules

I've imported a folder using git submodule. This folder contains a nuxt project. In my current project (also Nuxt) I need to access the store from the imported project.

*so say my structure looks like this:*

```
| Project
     |_ ImportedProject
     |    |_ store
     |        |_ index.js      
     |        |_ components.js      
     |_ CurrentProject
     |    |_ pages
     |        |_ index.vue
```

**currentProject/pages/index.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$store.commit('components/fillComponents')
  },
}
</script>
```

Above code obviously fails, because it is looking for components.js in the currentProject folder. The fillComponents is defined in the imported store, so importedProject/store/components.js needs to be accessed. How can I achieve this?